# $ \dfrac{d}{dz} \left \{ (1-z^2)P'(z) \right\} + \left\{ \beta - \dfrac{m^2}{1-z^2} \right\}P(z) = 0 $ Conversion of the DE into other forms.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential-geometry, polar-coordinates

I guess it's a bit related to physics, but the doubt is in the mathematical part.  I was just watching some stuff on Quantum Mechanics for the solution of the Hydrogen atom.

The lecture ends at..

$$ \dfrac{d}{dz} \left \{ (1-z^2)P'(z) \right\} + \left\{ \beta - \dfrac{m^2}{1-z^2} \right\}p(z) = 0 \tag{*}$$

And the next one starts after missing a few minutes at:

$$ Let \, P(z) = (1-z^2)^{|m|/2}G(z) $$

And $(*)$ changes to:

$$ (1-z^2)G''(z) - 2 (|m|+1)z G'(z) + \{ \beta - |m|(|m|+1)\}G(z) = 0 $$

How?

The closest I get is:

$$ (1-z^2)P''(z) - 2z P'(z) + \{ \beta - \dfrac{m^2}{1-z^2} \}P(z) = 0 $$

Can anyone show that to me?

A double derivative of $P$ is a very lengthy polynomial and seems of no use to me.
My approach was to eliminate the power $|m|/2$ and to get the constants in the form $\beta - |m|(|m|+1)$ but no order of the derivative is useful here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Wolfram gives [$(1 - z^2)^{|m|/2 - 1} ((z^2 - 1) |m| (2 z G'(z) + G(z)) + b (z^2 - 1) G(z) + (z^2 - 1) ((z^2 - 1) G''(z) + 2 x G'(z)) + m^2 (z^2 + 1) G(z))$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281-x%5E2%29%28%281-x%5E2%29%5E%28%7Cm%7C%2F2%29f%28x%29%29%27%27-2x%28%281-x%5E2%29%5E%28%7Cm%7C%2F2%29f%28x%29%29%27-%28b-%28%28m%5E2%29%2F%281-x%5E2%29%29%29%28%281-x%5E2%29%5E%28%7Cm%7C%2F2%29f%28x%29%29) so I don't see how they get the equation either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P(z) = (1-z^2)^{|m|/2}G(z)$

So $P'(z)=(1-z^2)^{|m|/2}G'(z)-|m|z(1-z^2)^{|m|/2-1}G(z)$

and $P''(z)=(1-z^2)^{|m|/2}G''(z)-2|m|z(1-z^2)^{|m|/2-1}G'(z)-|m|(1-z^2)^{|m|/2-1}G(z)+2|m|(|m|/2-1)(1-z^2)^{|m|/2-2}z^2G(z)$

Given equation is

$\dfrac{d}{dz} \left \{ (1-z^2)P'(z) \right\} + \left\{ \beta - \dfrac{m^2}{1-z^2} \right\}p(z) = 0 \tag{*}$

$\implies (1-z^2)P''(z)-2zP'(z)  + \left\{ \beta - \dfrac{m^2}{1-z^2} \right\}p(z) = 0 $

Putting the values of $~P(z)~$,$~P'(z)~$and $~P''(z)~$ in $(*)$ we have,

$ (1-z^2)\left\{(1-z^2)^{|m|/2}G''(z)-2|m|z(1-z^2)^{|m|/2-1}G'(z)-|m|(1-z^2)^{|m|/2-1}G(z)+2|m|(|m|/2-1)(1-z^2)^{|m|/2-2}z^2G(z)\right\}-2z\left\{(1-z^2)^{|m|/2}G'(z)-|m|z(1-z^2)^{|m|/2-1}G(z)\right\}  + \left\{ \beta - \dfrac{m^2}{1-z^2} \right\}\left\{(1-z^2)^{|m|/2}G(z)\right\} = 0$

$\implies (1-z^2)^{|m|/2+1}G''(z)-2|m|z(1-z^2)^{|m|/2}G'(z)-|m|(1-z^2)^{|m|/2}G(z)+2|m|(|m|/2-1)(1-z^2)^{|m|/2-1}z^2G(z)-2z(1-z^2)^{|m|/2}G'(z)+2|m|z^2(1-z^2)^{|m|/2-1}G(z)  + \left\{ \beta - \dfrac{m^2}{1-z^2} \right\}(1-z^2)^{|m|/2}G(z) = 0$

Taking common the term $~(1-z^2)^{|m|/2}~$ from the whole equation and eliminating we have , we have

$(1-z^2)G''(z)-2|m|zG'(z)-|m|G(z)+2|m|(|m|/2-1)(1-z^2)^{-1}z^2G(z)-2zG'(z)+2|m|z^2(1-z^2)^{-1}G(z)  + \left\{ \beta - \dfrac{m^2}{1-z^2} \right\}G(z) = 0$

$\implies (1-z^2)G''(z)-2(|m|+1)zG'(z)+\left[-|m|+2|m|(|m|/2-1)(1-z^2)^{-1}z^2+2|m|z^2(1-z^2)^{-1}+ \left\{ \beta - \dfrac{m^2}{1-z^2} \right\}\right]G(z)= 0$

$\implies (1-z^2)G''(z) - 2 (|m|+1)z G'(z) + \{ \beta - |m|(|m|+1)\}G(z) = 0$